# Execute PHP from Filemaker Script

Tags: php, filemaker

How do I run a PHP script on my apache server from a FileMaker script? I've tried `Open URL` & `Insert From URL` and neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert from URL absolutely works, just make sure you have the correct URL. You can also use a web viewer to initiate the script as well. You can inspect the contents of the web viewer or look at the field you pointed to with your Insert from URL script step.

One point to using the Insert from URL step, make sure the target field is on the layout when this step is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a FileMaker server , you can directly access command line .

For executing any script , you can execute shellscript like

```
php file.php
```

But for executing commandline scripts , you need to use some plugins like MBS .